# Wordpress 3.5 query pagination not functioning properly

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am using Wordpress and a static homepage and a posts page to display all my news posts located here: http://www.bigideaadv.com/uptous/?page_id=13

The pagination only works on page 1 and 2. Page 3 causes errors. Also, if I try and add more posts, the pagination doesn't go above three pages.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Posts query to follow:

```
    $posts = query_posts($query_string.'&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=4&paged='.$paged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do pagination without any plugin :

```
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
  'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

Put it in your index.php and it should works !